# debounceTime send request each time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, debouncing

Async Validator sends request to JSON each time, when typing in Email form. It checks existing of email, for typing each letter. How can call server and check once, not on every single letter?

```
isEmailExist(): AsyncValidatorFn  {
   return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<any> => {
     return this.usersService.getUserByEmail(control.value).pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
        map(users => {
            if (users.some(user => user.email.toLowerCase() === control.value.toLowerCase())) {
               return { isExist: true };
            } else {
               return null;
            }
        })
     ) 
   }
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `debounceTime` operator must be piped after an Observable that emits `keyup` events.
You could use the [`fromEvent`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent) operator to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Merei, you can use `{updateOn:'blur'}`, see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#optimizing-performance-of-async-validators)

Another option is not use a validator and check isEmailExist in submit

And another option is that you "check" the email in a debounceTime but of the value changes.
Imagine you has a variable "check" and a control

```
  check=false;
  control=new FormControl('',Validators.required,this.customValidator().bind(this))
```

the `bind(this)`make that you can use a variable of your component, so your customValidator can be like

```
  customValidator(){
    return (control)=>{
    if (!this.check)  //if the variable in component is false return of(null)
      return of(null)
                      //else you call to the service
     return this.usersService.getUserByEmail(control.value).pipe(
       map(users => {
          if (users.some(user => user.email.toLowerCase() ===
                                   control.value.toLowerCase())) {
              return { isExist: true };
          } else {
             return null;
          }
     })
    }
  }
```

Now, after define the FormControl you subscribe to valueChanges

```
this.control.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(300)).subscribe(_=>{
  this.check=true;
  this.control.updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false});
  this.check=false;
})
```

In [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2xu554?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I simulate the call to your service with a fool function